# FlowDocumentScrollViewer won't scroll

Tags: wpf, xaml, scroll, flowdocument

I'm trying to find the most expandable way to show a `FlowDocument` inside a window - just a `FlowDocument`. I have:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer x:Name="message" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
```

Then in the constructor for the Window, I set the Document of the viewer to one I load from XAML (in code). The XAML contains:

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Background="{x:Null}"
          FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe UI"  PagePadding="2">
<BlockUIContainer>
    <BlockUIContainer.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
    </BlockUIContainer.Resources>
    <StackPanel MaxWidth="200">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DefinedWord}" FontWeight="Bold"  />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Definitions}"
                 Style="{StaticResource InvisibleListBox}" Margin="0"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="false">
...
```

No matter what I try, the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` does not scroll and I can't see the truncated parts of the document. Does it have anything to do with the `BlockUIContainer`, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

I eventually got this working by setting the `ListBox` inside the document to `IsHitTestVisible="false"`, then binding the `Width`  of a text block inside the `ListBoxItem` template to the `ActualWidth` of the `ListBoxItem`.

Answer (score 0):

[Flexible Content Display With Flow Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163371.aspx)

> SUMMARY: FlowDocumentScrollViewer -
>   This control displays documents in a
>   continuous flow with a scrollbar,
>   similar to Web pages or the Web Layout
>   in Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 0):

For me alternate option to `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` worked,

See the example in,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx

The other options may be `FlowDocumentPageViewer`, `FlowDocumentReader`.